# C++ Creating Array of Objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm having an issue with making one array with 3 objects. I'm trying to display the information of employees and my issue is that I don't know where I would assign the strings to the appropriate members and how to keep one variable for name. My code and an example are below:

```
class employee
{
private:                
    string name;
    string idNumber;

public:                 
    void setName(string);
    void setIDnumber(string);
    string getName();
    string getIDnumber();

};

const int numEmployees = 3;

int main()
{

    employee employeeInfo [numEmployees];
}
```

I want to create a constructor for 3 employees and input(name, idNumber). for example, in employeeInfo[0], the first employee, I want to input "Tom Jones", "123456"
and in employee[1], the second employee, "James Blyth", "QE123"

Comment: Are you familiar with the notions of [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and [Implicitly-declared default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan yes but not much

Comment: @David___S__ How would you initialize a single `employeeInfo`, let alone an array of them?  You've seemed to have skipped over the basic concept of constructors.

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays generally? `employeeInfo[0]` will be the first `employee` in the array, `employeeInfo[1]` will be the second, etc. There's not really anything special about it being an array of `employee` objects as opposed to an array of `int`s or `float`s or something.

Comment: So for example you could call `employeeInfo[0].setName("Tom Jones");` to set the name of the first `employee` in the array to "Tom Jones" and `employeeInfo[1].setIDnumber("QE123")`

Comment: @NathanPierson thanks. this is my first time doing objects in c++ and it's with an array which I not a master at so I was pretty confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call the setter methods on the individual `employee` objects, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    employee employeeInfo [numEmployees];

    employeeInfo[0].setName("Tom Jones");
    employeeInfo[0].setIDNumber("123456");

    employeeInfo[1].setName("James Blyth");
    employeeInfo[1].setIDNumber("QE123");

    // and so on...

    ...
}
```

If you really want to add a constructor, then it would look like this:

```cpp
class employee
{
private:                
    string name;
    string idNumber;

public:                 
    employee() = default;
    employee(string name, string idNumber);

    ...
};

employee::employee(string name, string idNumber) {
    setName(name);
    setIDnumber(idNumber);
};

...
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    employee employeeInfo [numEmployees];

    employeeInfo[0] = employee("Tom Jones", "123456");
    employeeInfo[1] = employee("James Blyth", "QE123");
    // and so on...
}
```

Just note that this will default-construct the array elements first, and then construct temporary objects to overwrite the array elements.

If you want to avoid the temporaries, but still want a fixed array of objects stored consecutively, you can use `placement-new` to construct the array members directly using your non-default constructor, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(employee), alignas(employee)> buffer[numEmployees];
    employee* employeeInfo = reinterpret_cast<employee*>(buffer);

    new(&employeeInfo[0]) employee("Tom Jones", "123456");
    new(&employeeInfo[1]) employee("James Blyth", "QE123");
    // and so on...

    ...

    for(int i = 0; i < numEmployees; ++i) {
        employeeInfo[i].~employee();
    }
}
```

Or, you can use a `std::vector` (if you don't mind the array being allocated in dynamic memory), eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<employee> employeeInfo;
    employeeInfo.reserve(numEmployees);

    employeeInfo.emplace("Tom Jones", "123456");
    employeeInfo.emplace("James Blyth", "QE123");
    // and so on...

    ...
}
```

Otherwise, create an array of *pointers* to objects instead, and then you can create the individual objects dynamically using `new` with your non-default constructor.  The objects just won't be stored consecutively in memory, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    employee* employeeInfo[numEmployees];

    employeeInfo[0] = new employee("Tom Jones", "123456");
    employeeInfo[1] = new employee("James Blyth", "QE123");
    // and so on...

    ...

    for(int i = 0; i < numEmployees; ++i) {
        delete employeeInfo[i];
    }
}
```

Which would be safer handled with `std::unique_ptr`, eg:

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<employee> employeeInfo[numEmployees];

    employeeInfo[0] = std::make_unique<employee>("Tom Jones", "123456");
    employeeInfo[1] = std::make_unique<employee>("James Blyth", "QE123");
    // and so on...

    ...
}
```